Pseudo element Z-index issue. Can't position container with white background above pseudo element with red border
I have 5 boxes, and each of them has a white background.
I want to position a separate pseudo elements behind these element that move on hover. The pseudo elements are placed, but the issue is, that they are above the white background. I need to run behind it.


.beige-bg {
  background-color: #ebd7c5;
}

.red-bg {
  background-color: #8e221c;
}

.redlight-bg {
  background-color: #92483c;
}

.green-bg {
  background-color: #708669;
}

.white-bg {
  background-color: white;
}

.white {
  color: white !important;
}

.orange {
  color: #eaa15e !important;
}

body {
  color: #181c25;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  color: #eaa15e;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

p,
ul,
ol {
  margin: 0 0 1.65em 0;
  color: #525866;
}

p,
li {
  line-height: 1.65;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eaa15e;
}

.araink-section1 {
  transition: 300ms all ease-in-out;
  padding: 200px 0px;
}
.araink-section1 .container {
  gap: 4rem;
  align-items: center;
}
.araink-section1 .column {
  flex: 1 1 calc(33.33% - 4rem); /* First row: 3 columns */
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 4rem);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 450px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Optional: Adds hover effect */
  position: relative;
}
.araink-section1 .column p {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
.araink-section1 .red-subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  color: #8e221c;
}
.araink-section1 .column::after {
  border: 1px solid #8e221c;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Optional: Adds hover effect */
  content: "";
  z-index: 0; /* Ensure this is below the link wrapper */
}
.araink-section1 .column1::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -50px;
  left: -30px;
}
.araink-section1 .column2::after {
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
}
.araink-section1 .column3::after {
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}
.araink-section1 .column4::after {
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}
.araink-section1 .column5::after {
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}
.araink-section1 .column:hover::after {
  top: 50px;
  left: -20px;
}
.araink-section1 .section-headline {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Optima";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #8e221c;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}
.araink-section1 .green {
  color: #708669;
}
.araink-section1 .red-headline {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "optima";
  margin: 60px 0px 20px 0px;
  color: #8e221c;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.araink-section1 img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
.araink-section1 .green-btn {
  background-color: #708669;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #708669;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 300ms all ease-in-out;
}
.araink-section1 .green-btn:hover {
  color: #708669;
  background-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .araink-section1 .column::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .araink-section1 .column {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    flex: 1 1 100%; /* First row: 3 columns */
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- SZOLGÁLTATÁSOK -->


<div id="araink-section1" class="container-fluid beige-bg d-block d-md-block  araink-section1 szolgaltatasok">

    <div class="col-12  col-md-12 d-block justify-content-center ">
        <div class="section-container">
            <h3 class="section-headline red">
                Áraink
            </h3>
        </div>


        <div class="container d-block d-md-flex flex-wrap pt-5 justify-content-center">

            <div class="col-md-4 column column1">

                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/service1.png' ?>" alt="">
                <h4 class="red-headline">TÁJÉKOZTATÓ BESZÉLGETÉS</h4>
                <div class="red-subtitle">25.000 Ft</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 column column2">

                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/service2.png' ?>" alt="">
                <h4 class="red-headline">ELSŐ INTERJÚ(1-3 alkalom)</h4>
                <div class="red-subtitle">25.000 Ft / 45 perc</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 column column3">

                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/service3.png' ?>" alt="">
                <h4 class="red-headline">Online terápia</h4>
                <div class="red-subtitle">24.000 Ft / 45 perc</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 column column4">

                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/service3.png' ?>" alt="">
                <h4 class="red-headline">EGYÉNI Felnőtt terápia</h4>
                <div class="red-subtitle">23.000 Ft / 45 perc</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 column column5">

                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/service3.png' ?>" alt="">
                <h4 class="red-headline">Gyermek és serdülőterápiák</h4>
                <div class="red-subtitle">23.000 Ft / 45 perc</div>


            </div>
        </div>




    </div>


</div>



I tried reading through the Mozilla cdn documentation of layering context but I can't figure out what is causing this issue. Any help in the right direction is appreciated!
*Please view the code on a larger screen as the pseudo elements are hidden on smaller screens.

I managed to fix the issue by adding:
z-index: 1;
to the .container, and adding
z-index: -1;
to .column::after, but I still don't fully understand why this works. :)
